# Bad ptr on bmp read c

Tags: c, bmp

I get a  error on the following code:

```
FILE    *fp;
int     patno;
int     h, i, j, l, m;
int     i1, i2, i3;


 if( (fp=fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL ) {
    printf("\"%s\" not found!!\n", filename);
    return(-1);
}

for( h=0; h<4; h++ ) {
    l = 0;
    for( i3 = 0; i3 < 3; i3++ ) {
        for( i2 = 0; i2 < PATTERN_HEIGHT; i2++ ) {
            for( i1 = 0; i1 < PATTERN_WIDTH; i1++ ) {
                if( fscanf(fp, "%d", &j) != 1 ) {
                    printf("Pattern Data read error!!\n");
                    return -1;
                }
                 --..rest of code..--
```

the file exists and the path is right, the line `if(fscanf(fp...)` the pointer fp has the value of `0x00000000<Bad ptr>..`

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not C++, it's C; why did you mark it with [tag:c++]?

Comment: Is this happening on the first iteration of the loop? Are you doing anything else with `fp` inside any of those loops?

Comment: Code looks fine to me, I suspect it must be somewhere else. Is fp 0x0000 on the very first call to if?

Comment: Yeah sorry I'm working in C++ but using C lib's for some stuff.
Yes it's the first iteration of the loop, and fp is only used before in fopen

Comment: @Griwes: What makes you think this is C and not C++? As far as I can see, you can't tell by looking at the code.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, because it's valid C, therefore it uses none of C++ features, therefore it's plain C, therefore it's not C++ ;)

Comment: @Griwes: So it's okay if I give him an answer with an integer variable called `class` in it? `int class;` is valid C, right? It makes a huge difference whether the OP is using C or C++, and you *can't* tell from his code. If he had tagged it `C`, he might very well get inappropriate answers, such as answers that aren't valid C++ and so would lead him astray.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, still, it's not C++, therefore it shouldn't be tagged so. And naming variables `class` is plainly wrong.

Comment: The problem is in "rest of code" ... it's probably stomping on the stack and zeroing fp.

Comment: @Griwes: It is 100% valid C++. And the OP wants C++ answers. He's using C++.

Comment: It doesn't even reach the rest of the code, that's the problem

Comment: Use the debugger to set a watchpoint on `fp` so it will break whenever `fp` changes value. Then you will see when and where it becomes `NULL`.

Comment: 'Seems like doing a "ferror" or "perror" call right after your fopen might help you out a bit' -- not relevant, and `ferror` is useless after `fopen`.

Comment: 'It doesn't even reach the rest of the code, that's the problem' -- The problem is that you're misdiagnosing your problem. Clearly fp cannot be NULL on the first iteration. No one here will be able to explain why it is.

Comment: okay I'm sorry, fp itself has a value, but the value inside that pointer (like _ptr) says it's 0x00000000 <Bad Ptr>.

Comment: 'the value inside that pointer (like _ptr) says it's 0x00000000 <Bad Ptr>.' -- How do you know this? If you're looking at _ptr before scanf has attempted to read anything, it probably will be 0.

Comment: Eh, SO is spoiling, what happened to strict language tag policy that used to recommend changing "C++" to "C" when no C++ feature was used?

Comment: anyways the pointer is right, as @Jim Balter said the fp changes after using fscanf, but fscanf returns 0 instead of 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fscanf is returning 0 instead of 1 because bmp files don't contain numbers in textual form. You need to open the file in binary (mode "rb") and extract fields with fread.